# Move objects with mouse

Tags: django, web-deployment

I would like to have objects that user can move with mouse from place to place (like moving the cards between columns in Trello or GitHub projects). How do I approach this in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with javascript, there's a good example in this link:
[W3 Schools Code](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrag_all)

And there's one simplier here : [W3 Schools Code](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2)

Answer (score 2):

This is handled using javascript. If you wanted to roll your own you could [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) or the [draggable](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/) library